# Is there a method to write the entire sheet with the list of dictionary get back from the method get_all_records()?

Tags: python, gspread

I really like the method get_all_records(), which gives back to me a list of dictionaries.  I wonder is there a twin method, maybe called "insert_records()", that can take the exact same thing (list of dictionaries) and write into the sheet.  I know it's implementable with the current api, but just in case I missed it.  After all, I think it makes a lot of sense to have a twin method to write if there is one to read.

Comment: Please add more details or explain in bried.

Comment: Add the Python tag and reformat your message too, please.